# Many to Many Relation with Lookup table Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create many to many relation with a Lookup table. Suppose i have a table "Course" that has 3 possible courses :

```
Course
Id | Name
1  | History
2  | Maths
3  | Science
```

I have another table Students where I will create Students such as :

```
Student
Id | Name
```

I have a mapping table which is StudentCourse:

```
StudentCourse
ID | StudentId | CourseId
1  |   1       | 3
```

Here is my Student & Course class:

```
public class Student : Entity<Student,int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course : Entity<Course,int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, here is the configuration code:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasMany<Course>(s => s.Courses)
                .WithMany(c => c.Students)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("CourseId");
                            cs.ToTable("StudentCourse");
                        });
```

When i create Student entity from view , the user selects the course from Course table and sends it to entity framework and EF should make entry to only Student and StudentCourse table .

But in my scenario, the course table is getting new entries for the selected courses. So I end up with duplicates in course table.

How do I tell entity framework to not make entry in Course table as it already has all the possible courses ... Please help !!

Comment: Use either Distinct or a Group By to remove duplicates.

Comment: Avoid passing entities to/from your view, use ViewModels with the relevant IDs.When you get back to the server, create your Student entities and retrieve the relevant Courses based on the selected IDs then associate those to the new Student entities via their Courses collection, add the Students to the context DBSet and SaveChanges. The alternative if you are passing "Course" entities is that you'll need to remember to associate them to the DbContext where you are adding your students, otherwise you'll end up with these duplicates. IMO, leave the Entites at the service/controller level.

Comment: a code sample can help ? I am new to entity framework ..               
 @jdweng how do i code Distinct ?

Comment: Just add .Distinct() to end of query.

Comment: Which query ? I am using entity framework ...

Comment: `.Distinct()` will only hide the problem. Your issue is you are getting duplicate records because EF doesn't realize they already exist. Need to see your code where you do the update, but see [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-many-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) for guidance on how to update many to many.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that I was populating my object in presentation layer and hence dbcontext under unit of work did not know about the nested objects.That is why it will always try to re create the Course even if it already exists. To fix this, populate Course object under same unit of work dbcontext.

ex:

```
  student.Course = UnitOfWork.Repository.FindById(id);
  var model = UnitOfWork.Repository.Add(student);
```